# How to check existing versions in Test Flight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I'm uploading the new version to the TF, but getting the error, that this version is already exists. When looking to the TF console at the https://appstoreconnect.apple.com there are no builds at all. Guess, that there was a build with the same version, but it has been stopped.

How to check what build versions are already uploaded to TF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If go to ITC (AppStoreConnect) -> App -> Functions there would be shown all builds.